# Is it possible to create a Generic Dataloader in HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to create a graphql server with standard query and mutations for any Entity I supply in a generic way i.e. I read in the configuration from somewhere, create the entities in memory and then create the graphql server.

I am currently able to create a generic type to query all the details but I don't seem to be able to create a generic dataloader to efficiently retrieve records by Id.

```
query GetSpecificSpeakerById {
  byId(id: 1) {
    name
  }
}
```

Or

```
query GetSpecificSpeakerById {
  a: byId(id: 1) {
    name
  }
  b: byId(id: 2) {
    name
  }
}
```

The schema seems to generated correctly but I receive the following when executing the query:

```
{
  "name": "ServerError",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "statusText": "Internal Server Error",
  "bodyText": "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"The ID \\u00601\\u0060 has an invalid format.\"}]}"
}
```

I currently have the following code:

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=conferences.db"));

        var entityType = typeof(Speaker);            
        Type queryType = typeof(GenericQuery<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

        Type dataLoaderType = typeof(GenericrByIdDataLoader<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

        services
                .AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddQueryType(queryType)
                .AddDataLoader<GenericrByIdDataLoader<Speaker>>();                   
    }
```

GenericByIdDataLoader.cs

```
public class GenericrByIdDataLoader<TEntity> : BatchDataLoader<int, TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _dbContextFactory;

        public GenericrByIdDataLoader(
            IBatchScheduler batchScheduler,
            IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
            : base(batchScheduler)
        {
            _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContextFactory));
        }

        protected override async Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<int, TEntity>> LoadBatchAsync(
            IReadOnlyList<int> keys,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await using ApplicationDbContext dbContext =
                _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

            return await dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                .Where(s => keys.Contains(s.Id))
                .ToDictionaryAsync(t => t.Id, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

GenericQuery.cs

```
public class GenericQuery<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{       
    [UseApplicationDbContext]
    public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll([ScopedService] ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        return await context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(
        [ID(nameof(TEntity))] int id,
        GenericrByIdDataLoader<TEntity> dataLoader,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return dataLoader.LoadAsync(id, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

IEntity.cs

```
public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Speaker.cs

```
public class Speaker : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string? Bio { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public virtual string? WebSite { get; set; }
    }
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks